# How to filter on enum and include all rows if no filter value provided

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, enums

I'm working on a project resource management application and my resource table has several fields, one of which is an enum as below:

```
CREATE TYPE "clearance" AS ENUM (
  'None',
  'Baseline',
  'NV1',
  'NV2',
  'TSPV'
);
```

Then, my resource table includes that enum:

```
CREATE TABLE "resource" (
  "employee_id" integer PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" varchar NOT NULL,
  "email" varchar NOT NULL,
  "job_title_id" integer NOT NULL,
  "manager_id" integer NOT NULL,
  "workgroup_id" integer NOT NULL,
  "clearance_level" clearance,
  "specialties" text[],
  "certifications" text[],
  "active" boolean DEFAULT 't'
);
```

When querying the data, I want to be able to provide query string parameters in the url, that then apply filters to the database query.

For example (using a local dev machine):

```
curl localhost:6543/v1/resources # returns all resources in a paginated query
curl localhost:6543/v1/resources?specialties=NSX  # returns all resources with NSX as a specialty
curl localhost:6543/v1/resources?manager=John+Smith # returns resources that report to John Smith
curl localhost:6543/v1/resources?jobTitle=Senior+Consultant # returns all Senior Consultants
```

etc.

Where I'm running into an issue though is that I also want to be able to filter on the security clearance level like this:

```
curl localhost:6543/v1/resources?clearance=NV2
```

When I provide a clearance filter I can get the query to work fine:

```
query := fmt.Sprintf(`
        SELECT count(*) OVER(), r.employee_id, r.name, r.email, job_title.title, m.name AS manager, workgroup.workgroup_name, r.clearance_level, r.specialties, r.certifications, r.active
        FROM (((resource r
            INNER JOIN job_title ON r.job_title_id=job_title.title_id)
            INNER JOIN resource m ON r.manager_id=m.employee_id)
            INNER JOIN workgroup ON workgroup.workgroup_id=r.workgroup_id)
        WHERE (workgroup.workgroup_name = ANY($1) OR $1 = '{}')
        AND (r.clearance_level = $2::clearance)
        AND (r.specialties @> $3 OR $3 = '{}')
        AND (r.certifications @> $4 OR $4 = '{}')
        AND (m.name = $5 OR $5 = '')
        AND (r.active = $6)
        AND (r.name = $7 OR $7 = '')
        ORDER BY %s %s, r.employee_id ASC
        LIMIT $8 OFFSET $9`, clearance_filter, fmt.Sprintf("r.%s", filters.sortColumn()), filters.sortDirection())
```

However, I can't figure out a reasonably way to implement the filtering, so that all results are returned when no clearance filter is provided.

The poor way I have made it work is to just apply an empty string filter on another field when no clearance is filtered for and substitute in the correct filter when a clearance argument is provided.

It works, but smells really bad:

```
func (m *ResourceModel) GetAll(name string, workgroups []string, clearance string, specialties []string,
    certifications []string, manager string, active bool, filters Filters) ([]*Resource, Metadata, error) {
    // THIS IS A SMELL
    // Needed to provide a blank filter parameter if all clearance levels should be returned.
    // Have not found a good way to filter on enums to include all values when no filter argument is provided
    var clearance_filter = `AND (r.name = $2 OR $2 = '')`
    if clearance != "" {
        clearance_filter = `AND (r.clearance_level = $2::clearance)`
    }

    query := fmt.Sprintf(`
        SELECT count(*) OVER(), r.employee_id, r.name, r.email, job_title.title, m.name AS manager, workgroup.workgroup_name, r.clearance_level, r.specialties, r.certifications, r.active
        FROM (((resource r
            INNER JOIN job_title ON r.job_title_id=job_title.title_id)
            INNER JOIN resource m ON r.manager_id=m.employee_id)
            INNER JOIN workgroup ON workgroup.workgroup_id=r.workgroup_id)
        WHERE (workgroup.workgroup_name = ANY($1) OR $1 = '{}')
        %s
        AND (r.specialties @> $3 OR $3 = '{}')
        AND (r.certifications @> $4 OR $4 = '{}')
        AND (m.name = $5 OR $5 = '')
        AND (r.active = $6)
        AND (r.name = $7 OR $7 = '')
        ORDER BY %s %s, r.employee_id ASC
        LIMIT $8 OFFSET $9`, clearance_filter, fmt.Sprintf("r.%s", filters.sortColumn()), filters.sortDirection())
...
...
}
```

Is there a better way to approach this?

It feels like a really poor solution to the point that I'm thinking of dropping the enum and making it another table that just establishes a domain of values:

```
CREATE TABLE clearance (
 "level" varchar NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: `AND (r.clearance_level = $2::clearance OR $2::text = '')`. You already seem to be using this approach with every other column in the where clause, why not with clearance?

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for the suggestion. I had tried something similar before, without casting it to text since it already is text. However in both instances this results in an 'invalid input for enum' error when no filter is provided.

Comment: @mkopriva, thanks. I slightly changed what you proposed and it works.

So the solution is to cast the clearance_level to text:

UPDATE: 
I got it, thanks to the approach above. What worked was casting the clearance_level to text.

This works:

AND (r.clearance_level::text = $2 OR $2 = '')

Much appreciated for thinking outside the box. That really helped and I feel it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that needs this very niche use case in the future, the answer was built on the initial hint from @mkopriva

The approach was to cast the clearance_level to text, so the filter is:

```
...
AND(r.clearance_level::text = $2 OR $2 = '')
...
```

This returns all results, regardless of clearance when no clearance filter is provided and returns only the result that match the provided clearance_level when a filter is provided.

Must appreciated to @mkopriva for the assistance.